# Adding "\exists !" to the nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature

I get several errors on trying to add "\exists !" to the nomenclature.

Does someone can help?

Here my MWE (sorry for the makeindex, I don't want to change my build-command and without changing it, it completely fails)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makeindex

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
dummy
\nomenclature{$\exists$}{exists}
%\nomenclature{$\exists !$}{exists exactly one} %error
%\nomenclature{$\exists!$}{exists exactly one} %error
\nomenclature{$\exists$!}{exists exactly one} %no effect

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

---

**Solution:**

```
\nomenclature{$\exists"!$}{exists exactly one}
```

Comment: What happens if you make `$\exists\; !$`?

Comment: Try `\nomenclature{$\exists"!$}{...}` The character ! Is special for makeindex and has to be quoted

Comment: @juanuni doesn't work

Comment: @egreg thanks. I added your solution to the question

Comment: @Ben I'm on the road now. I'll add an answer later, if none comes along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some characters are special for MakeIndex:

```
! @ | ( ) "
```

and they should be quoted when in an index entry; it doesn't matter whether it is `\nomenclature`, because it uses the same framework as `\index`. Quoting is obtained by prefixing the special character with `"`. Thus

```
\nomenclature{$\exists"!$}{exists exactly one}
```

should do.

Comment: Quoting `|` doesn't help for me. Using `\vert` is an alternative