# Special characters you should be careful when using in nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature

I'm struggling to write |.| in nomenclature in LaTeX.
It works for the first item in the nomenclature, but not working for the second item in the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\item[\textbf{Constants}]}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{V}}{\item[\textbf{Variables}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{K}}{\item[\textbf{Symbols}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{sets}]}{}}}}
}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\nomenclature[Km]{$\leftarrow\cdot\rightarrow$}{Number of element in a set.} %
\nomenclature[Km]{$\left|\cdot \right|$}{Number of element in a set.} %
Say something.
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Can any one help me with it, why it is not showing up?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem and not just a code snippet. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @albert I do not think it is about making index because I am able to see first item in the nomenclature but not the second item.

Comment: Without the makeindex I didn't see anything, with the makeindex I did see the first item. A bit strange that the second one is not present. Must have to do with the `|` symbol.

Comment: Related: [Adding “\exists !” to the nomenclature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324639)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thanks, added findings from your reference to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been searching a bit and found the following solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath} % <=== don't forget
\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\item[\textbf{Constants}]}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{V}}{\item[\textbf{Variables}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{K}}{\item[\textbf{Symbols}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{sets}]}{}}}}
}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\nomenclature[Km]{$\leftarrow\cdot\rightarrow$}{Number of element in a set.} %
\nomenclature[Km]{$ \left\lvert \cdot \right\rvert $}{Number of element in a set.} %
%% based on the comment from @NicolaTalbot and the answer from @egreg in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324639/adding-exists-to-the-nomenclature
\nomenclature[Km]{$ \left"| \cdot \right"| $}{Number of element in a set.} %
Say something.
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```